Show that $f(X)$ is universally measurable if $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is universally measurable
Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a universally measurable set and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. How can I show that $f(X)$ is universally measurable?

On the paper "On Perfect Measures" by V.V. Sazonov, we have the following result: $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is universally measurable iff every finite Borel measure on $\mathfrak{B}(X)$ is perfect. I'm trying to use this result to prove that $f[X]$ is universally measurable, but I'm stuck.

EDIT:
I know the following result that may be helpful.

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a countably generated measurable space. If every finite measure $\mu
 :\Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$ is perfect, then $f(X)$ is universally
measurable for all measurable functions $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$\Sigma =\{f^{-1}(B):B\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$.

